# Is it nessary to disable log ouput for release build

Tags: pjsip

I read some pjsip document, found out that could set log-level to zero.

But I don't find many information about disable log-output in compile time.

Please suggest. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

set log-level to zero.
not necessary disable log-output.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the **max** log level to zero. The relevant line in log.h :

```
#if PJ_LOG_MAX_LEVEL >= 1
```